# NodeMCU keeps running the previous program

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

After countless days and hours, I finally can upload my sketch into my NodeMCU successfully. But, just after that, I've got another problem.
If you've checked my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72709672/how-can-i-fix-this-error-of-esp8266-warning-espcomm-sync-failed-error-espcom), you'll see I have two sketches. The first one is at my question and the second one is at my answer. After uploading the second one, I decided to upload another sketch, which is the first sketch. But when I check the result after the IDE says: "Done uploading", I know that the NodeMCU is running the previous program (which is written in my second sketch) based on what the Serial Monitor has printed. What I want is the result of my first sketch, not this. Anyone can help?

Comment: Did you press the `reset` after uploading?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried several times and it finally works.